# Merging two arrays of objects with one being used as a master overwriting any duplicates

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays of objects. Each object within that array has an array of objects.

I'm trying to merge the two arrays with one being used as a master, overwriting any duplicates in both the first level and the second 'option' level. Almost like a union join.

I've tried the code, however this doesn't cater for duplicate in options within a material.

Running this code results in two `id: 400` options for the second material. When there should only be 1 with the value of `100cm`.

Is there any smart way of doing this please? I also had a look at using sets, but again this only worked on the top level.

```js
const materials_list = [
  {
    id: 2,
    options: [
      {
        id: 300,
        value: '50cm'
      },
      {
        id: 400,
        value: '75cm'
      }
    ]
  }
]

const master_materials_list = [
  {
    id: 1,
    options: [
      {
        id: 200,
        value: '50cm'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    options: [
      {
        id: 400,
        value: '100cm'
      }
    ]
  }
]

master_materials_list.forEach(masterMaterial => {
  const matchMaterial = materials_list.find(existingMaterial => existingMaterial.id === masterMaterial.id);
  
   if(matchMaterial) {
    masterMaterial.options = masterMaterial?.options.concat(matchMaterial.options);
  }
  
});

console.log(master_materials_list);
```

This is the desired output

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    options: [
      {
        id: 200,
        value: '50cm'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    options: [
      {
        id: 300,
        name: '50cm'
      },
      {
        id: 400,
        name: '100cm'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different approach that first makes a Map of the material_list options for o(1) lookup

Then when mapping the master list use `filter()` to find options stored in the above Map that don't already exist in the master

```js
const materials_list=[{id:2,options:[{id:300,value:"50cm"},{id:400,value:"75cm"}]}, {id:999, options:[]}],
     master_materials_list=[{id:1,options:[{id:200,value:"50cm"}]},{id:2,options:[{id:400,value:"100cm"}]}];
     
// store material list options array in a Map keyed by option id    
const listMap = new Map(materials_list.map(o=>[o.id, o]));
// used to track ids found in master list
const masterIDs = new Set()

// map material list and return new objects to prevent mutation of original
const res = master_materials_list.map(({id, options, ...rest})=>{
   // track this id
    masterIDs.add(id)
  // no need to search if the material list Map doesn't have this id
  if(listMap.has(id)){
    // Set of ids in this options array in master
    const opIds = new Set(options.map(({id}) => id));
    // filter others in the Map for any that don't already exist
    const newOpts = listMap.get(id).options.filter(({id})=> !opIds.has(id));
    // and merge them       
    options = [...options, ...newOpts]
  }
   // return the new object
   return {id, options, ...rest};
});

// add material list items not found in master to results
listMap.forEach((v,k) =>{
   if(!masterIDs.has(k)){
       res.push({...v})
   }  
})



console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0}
```

Comment: So this works until the material list has a new item that the master list doesn't have. Is there anyway to add any items to the list that aren't on the master list?

Comment: Check the update. Added a `Set` to track ids found in the master. Then added a step at end to go through the listMap and push new ones into results

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [lodash](https://lodash.com/):

```js
const materials_list = [
  {
    id: 2,
    options: [
      {
        id: 300,
        value: '50cm',
      },
      {
        id: 400,
        value: '75cm',
      },
    ],
  },
];

const master_materials_list = [
  {
    id: 1,
    options: [
      {
        id: 200,
        value: '50cm',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    options: [
      {
        id: 400,
        value: '100cm',
      },
    ],
  },
];

const customizer = (objValue, srcValue, propertyName) => {
  if (propertyName === 'options') {
    return _(srcValue)
      .keyBy('id')
      .mergeWith(_.keyBy(objValue, 'id'))
      .values()
      .value();
  }
};

const merged = _(master_materials_list)
  .keyBy('id')
  .mergeWith(_.keyBy(materials_list, 'id'), customizer)
  .values()
  .value();

console.log(merged);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re going to have to filter matchMaterials.options before the concat. Something like:

```
matchMaterial.options = matchMaterial.options.filter(opt =>
    masterMaterial.options.find(val => val.Id === opt.Id) == null;
);
```

This should remove any “duplicate” options from matchMaterial before the concat.

EDIT:
I did this on my phone so I’m sorry if the code is formatted weird like I’m seeing now